d3-shape links are too thick
While charting a tree in d3, some link paths are oddly thicker than others. I would like for the wider paths seen in the image to be the same thickness as the vertical paths. Can anyone help me find the problem? In most tree examples I'm finding, the link lines are usually uniform.

Tree
const stratifier = stratify<Leaf>()
  .id((d) => d.name)
  .parentId((d) => d.parentName)

const root = useMemo(() => {
  if (loading) return null
  if (error) return null
  if (data?.leaves.length === 0 || data === undefined) return null

  const leaves =
    data?.leaves.map((leaf) => ({
      name: leaf.name,
      description: leaf.description,
      parentName: leaf.parentName ?? '',
      children:
        leaf.children?.map((leaf) => ({
          name: leaf?.name ?? '',
        })) ?? [],
    })) ?? []

  return stratifier(leaves)
}, [data, stratifier, loading, error])

const setupTree = useMemo(() => {
  if (!root) return
  const result = tree<Leaf>().size([500, 500])(root)
  return result
}, [root])

const links = useMemo(() => setupTree?.links(), [setupTree])
const convertLink = useCallback(
  (link: HierarchyPointLink<Leaf>): DefaultLinkObject => ({
    source: [link.source.x, link.source.y],
    target: [link.target.x, link.target.y],
  }),
[])

jsx path(s)
{links?.map((link, i) => {
  const convertedLink = convertLink(link)
  return (
    <path
      key={`${i}-link`}
      d={linkVertical()
        .source((d) => d.target)
        .target((d) => d.source)(convertedLink) ?? ''
      }
      stroke="black"
      strokeWidth="2"
      style={{ transform: `translate(${margin}px, ${margin}px)` }}
    />
  )
})}

Stratified data
{
    "data": {
        "leaves": [
            {
                "name": "A",
                "parentName": null,
                "description": "This is a description of A",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "B",
                        "__typename": "Leaf"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "C",
                        "__typename": "Leaf"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "D",
                        "__typename": "Leaf"
                    }
                ],
                "__typename": "Leaf"
            },
            {
                "name": "B",
                "parentName": "A",
                "description": "This is a description of B",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "B-1",
                        "__typename": "Leaf"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "B-2",
                        "__typename": "Leaf"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "B-3",
                        "__typename": "Leaf"
                    }
                ],
                "__typename": "Leaf"
            },
            {
                "name": "B-1",
                "parentName": "B",
                "description": "This is a description of B-1",
                "children": [],
                "__typename": "Leaf"
            },
            {
                "name": "B-2",
                "parentName": "B",
                "description": "This is a description of B-2",
                "children": [],
                "__typename": "Leaf"
            },
            {
                "name": "B-3",
                "parentName": "B",
                "description": "This is a description of B-3",
                "children": [],
                "__typename": "Leaf"
            },
            {
                "name": "C",
                "parentName": "A",
                "description": "This is a description of C",
                "children": [],
                "__typename": "Leaf"
            },
            {
                "name": "D",
                "parentName": "A",
                "description": "This is a description of D",
                "children": [],
                "__typename": "Leaf"
            }
        ]
    }
}


Probably the path for the link has not only a stroke but also a fill. Try adding fill="none" for the link shape.

I tried that already, but thanks

Ah, actually, that did work. I tried removing the stroke but not the fill last night. @enxaneta if you care to answer the question, I'm happy to accept it
